# how to make content to fit in container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make some graph widget in fixed sized box, so I tried make 'FittedBox' and then make BarChart there. but It occures an error like "RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#4496c NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'"

To be specific, I want to make like picture1 but now the situation is graph is fulled with screen like picture2. How can I make it in some fixed sized container like picture1?

[image: picture1]
[image: picture2]

```
    return new Container(
      // width: 100,
      // height: 100,
      // child: FittedBox(
      //   fit:BoxFit.contain,
        child: new Stack(
          children: [
            new charts.BarChart(seriesList,
                animate: animate,
                primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                      tickProviderSpec: new charts.StaticNumericTickProviderSpec(
                        <charts.TickSpec<num>>[
                          charts.TickSpec(0.8, label: ''),
                          charts.TickSpec(0, label: '0'),
                          charts.TickSpec(0.38, label: '0.38'),
                          charts.TickSpec(0.67, label: '0.67'),
                          charts.TickSpec(0.96, label: '0.96'),
                          charts.TickSpec(1.25, label: '1.25'),
                        ],
                      ),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show more above the Container...

Answer (score 0):

```
return new Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(),
      // width: 100,
      // height: 100,
      // child: FittedBox(
      //   fit:BoxFit.contain,
        child: new Stack(
          children: [
            new charts.BarChart(seriesList,
                animate: animate,
                primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                      tickProviderSpec: new charts.StaticNumericTickProviderSpec(
                        <charts.TickSpec<num>>[
                          charts.TickSpec(0.8, label: ''),
                          charts.TickSpec(0, label: '0'),
                          charts.TickSpec(0.38, label: '0.38'),
                          charts.TickSpec(0.67, label: '0.67'),
                          charts.TickSpec(0.96, label: '0.96'),
                          charts.TickSpec(1.25, label: '1.25'),
                        ],
                      ),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      
    );
```